# Xtext: formatting rule with no hidden terminals removes whitespaces

Tags: xtext

In my Xtext grammar I have a rule which doesn't have hidden terminals e.g.

```
Model:
    greetings+=Greeting*;

Greeting:
    'Tag' (tags+=HashTag)+ ';';

HashTag hidden():
    '#' name=ID 
;
```

All is working well, but when I format my file content (Shift+Alt+F) the spaces between HashTags are removed which creates one long HashTag...
E.g.
`Tag #a #b #c;` -> `Tag #a#b#c ;`

Any help?

Comment: sounds like a bug to me. can you file a ticket?

Comment: Done [Bug 476026](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=476026)